# Update access denied for Account : Site.createPortalUser

Tags: force.com-sites

I have configured Customer community where the landing pages of the active site is a VF page. As part of the VF page, i'm collecting accounts and Contact details. While users clicks a button, I will create a Portal user using "Site.createPortalUser" where I would pass the account id. This is throwing "system.security.NoAccessException: Update access denied for Account". Currently the Guest user has create and not edit access to Account.

Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue? Also, I'm not able to debug this issue even though I have the guest user in my debug logs.